# Devices On My Network Appear As VMware, Inc - Why?

Tags: kali-linux, vmware, nmap

When I use **Netdiscover** on Kali Linux, it shows **all my devices Brand as VMWare**, Inc, why?

[image]

Not just that, but the **same happens when I use Nmap, Zenmap, net.show with Bettercap,** nothing seems to show their true Brand, why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing from the MAC this is a VM and not a PC running workstation. The check there says "MAC vendor". All 00:50:56 MAC addresses are VMware, this includes all vNICs by default. Search the prefix "00:50:56" in the IEEE MAC Registrations and you will find those addresses under VMware https://regauth.standards.ieee.org/standards-ra-web/pub/view.html#registries

For some of the other ways you checked for the vendor one of those might have looked at the driver vendor as well. Check what NIC type is configured in the VM settings. If it is one of the VMXNET NICs, then it would use a driver that VMware provides and will have VMware as the driver vendor. From what the OS knows it is a NIC from VMware and doesn't access the hardware directly. You would need to look directly on the host to see what the pNICs are (or on the PC if using workstation).

https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1001805